# make space between TextSpan

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make space between TextSpan
What is the best way to add space between TextSpan?

```
child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Don\'t have an Account?',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 15.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
            
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Sign Up',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 15.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 13):

**[SizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html)** widget can be used in between two widgets to add space between two widgets.
use the `SizedBox` by wrapping it with a `WidgetSpan` widgit

```
child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Don\'t have an Account?',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 15.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
            ),
            WidgetSpan(
             child: SizedBox(width: 10),
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: 'Sign Up',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 15.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to get maximum space between text, you might go for `Row` widget. For x amount of space inside `RichText` you can use

```dart
TextSpan(...),
WidgetSpan(child: SizedBox(width: x)),
TextSpan(...),
```

```dart
RichText(
  text: const TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Don\'t have an Account?',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
          fontSize: 15.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
      ),

      WidgetSpan(child: SizedBox(width: 10)), ///this

      TextSpan(
        text: 'Sign Up',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
          fontSize: 15.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can mark while it answer your question, you can find more about [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **height** property on the TextStyle to create some spacing:

```
 RichText(
          text:  TextSpan(
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: 'Don\'t have an Account?',
                style: TextStyle(
                  height: 1.5, //USE THIS PROPERTY
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              TextSpan(
                text: 'Sign Up',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

More info in the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/height.html

Comment: You can't add SizeBoxes to the RichText's children. "The element type 'SizedBox' can't be assigned to the list type 'InlineSpan'. "